# How to integrate Hacker News REST API in Android

Tags: android, json, web-services, api

Integrating [Hacker News API](https://github.com/HackerNews/API) in Android app, total data is in the form of items, actually trying to display topstories in a ListView using this API https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty but data is in this format (Result of above API) `[ 11547212, 11546098, 11544988, 11546490, 11543083, 11544016, 11545112, 11545975, 11543258, 11541675, 11544510, 11543188, 11544254, 11544374, 11541702, 11545351, 11542995, 11542005, 11543646, 11540747, 11541834, 11541242, 11544686, 11544523, 11546077]` these are id's of each story as per documentation. So for displaying a list of Top-Stories what is the procedure.

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered over here. Have you tried anything? Are you stuck at some point of implementation? -- Normally such questions get a good response.

Comment: yea,i integrated this web service https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty ,didn't get how to get data of id from the result of this api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to load each item by id, for eaxmple use this

```
https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/item/11547212.json
```

where `11547212` is the item-id of the story you want to load. You will get basic meta information for this story, includeing author, URL and title.

You may also use firebase itself to access the data. There is a [Firebase SDK for Android](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-android#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-listview) available.

Comment: so i have to iterate over the above json result ?then number of network calls will be too much right?

Comment: The API seems to be built like that, why should a few requests be too many?

Comment: few requests means ? could you please explain ,suppose i want to get information of all these ids ,how to handle it

Comment: https://hacker-news.firebaseio.com/v0/topstories.json?print=pretty

Comment: Yeah ,i have checked firebase sdk,But i want to go ahead with Rest api only

Comment: Then you will have to send a request for each story.

Comment: Could you give some reference to do this if possible,thanks for your time.

Comment: @sri how did you resolve this ? can you help me out?